# How to add submenu to clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown list like this:
[image]

Which consists of a few buttons. On click on either of this marked buttons sub-menu should appear with some data that I'm getting via `AJAX`. So, eventually it should look like this:
[image]

This is the code of my dropdown:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <?php
                foreach($applications as $application){

                echo "<li><button type='button' style='width:100%;' value='".$application['facebook_id']."' onclick='setSession(this.value);'>".$application['app_name']."</button></li>";

                } ?>
                <?php if($resultForUpperQuery){
                echo '<hr>';
                while($names=$resultForUpperQuery->fetch_assoc()){
                $groupname=$names['ime_grupe'];
                echo "<li><button type='button' style='width:100%;' value='".$groupname."' onclick='showDetails(this.value);'>".$groupname."</button></li>";
                }
                echo '<hr>';
                }
                ?>
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['ap_id'])){
                echo '
                <li><a href="" data-target="#createAppGroup" data-toggle="modal">Create App Group</a></li>';}?>
                <li><a href="app_setup.php">Add new app</a></li>
    </ul>
```

So each button has `onclick="showDetails(this.value)"` functions which looks like this:

```
function showDetails(o){

            var data    = {};
            var groupName = o;

            data.action2='showConsistsOf';
            data.groupName=groupName;
            $.ajax({
                url: "../includes/adapter.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: data,
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data){
                        //console.log(data);
                        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        $('button[value=groupName]').append('<li>+data[i]+</li>');
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

And data retrieved looks like this:

```
["Notiflow", "Konfidence Hrvatska"]
```

So, its basically as array whose values should be part of submenu dropdown.
And I tried to make this submenu like this, as you can see from above code as well:

```
success: function (data) {
    if(data){
        console.log(data);
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            $('button[value=groupName]').append('<li>+data[i]+</li>');
        }
    }
}
```

So foreach value in data I tried to append `<li>` to button which click fired the function. But click on button just closes the dropdown. Really don't know how to solve this.

Comment: If you are trying to append the data[i] as a submenu you should append also the ul because the first ul is for the menu and you need a second one inside it.

Comment: Did it, still click on button just closes whole dropdown.

Comment: What your console log says in inspector after you click ?

Comment: it shows data that I presented in my question. ["Notiflow", "Konfidence Hrvatska"]. e.i it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your function it like this:

```
$(".dropdown-menu").on("click", ".button", function() {.......} );
```

Comment: Nothing happens. Plus I also think using any other way than this `onclick=function(value)` would not work for me because I need value of clicked button.

Comment: Ok than try to split the append of ul and li like this:
var li = $('<li+data[i]+</li>');
$(ul).append(li);

Comment: No, each click on button shuts down the menu.

Comment: Add also   event.preventDefault(); in the function.